# Compiling java class, 'illegal start of type' and '<identifier> expected' errors

Tags: java, java-11

Was practicing working with constructors in Java, heres the class I was trying to compile:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class mob{

    public Map enemies = new HashMap<String, Point>();
    public Point pn = new Point(1, 1);
    enemies.put("Peon", pn);
    public Point gn = new Point(5, 2);
    enemies.put("Goblin", gn);
    public Point tl = new Point(25, 8);
    enemies.put("Troll", tl);
    public Point oc = new Point(13, 5);
    enemies.put("Orc", oc);
    public String name;
    public int hp;
    public int dmg;

    public mob(String type){
      name=type;
      hp=enemies.get(type).getX();
      dmg=enemies.get(type).getY();
    }

    public mob(){
      name="Peon";
      hp=enemies.get("Peon").getX();
      dmg=enemies.get("Peon").getY();

    }

    void setName(String name){
            this.name=name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in());
      System.out.System.out.println("Enter mob type:");
      String type = scan.nextln();
      if(mob.containsKey(type)){
        mob mob1 = new mob(type);
      }
      else{
        mob mob1 = new mob();
        mob1.setName(type);
      }

      System.out.println("You just spawned a "+mob1.name+", it has "+mob1.hp+" hp and "+mob1.dmg+" dmg!");
    }
}
```

The main method is meant to take some input from the console and create a specific mob using data from a map ('enemies') or default mob depending on the input. But when i try to compile this in Command Prompt I get errors at all of the enemies.put() methods, i.e:

```
mob.java:7: error: <identifier> expected
    enemies.put("Peon", pn);
               ^
mob.java:7: error: illegal start of type
    enemies.put("Peon", pn);
               ^
mob.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
    enemies.put("Goblin", gn);
               ^
```

Etc.

Looked at similar issues and tried to fix things (hence all the public declarations) but can't figure this one out...

Using Java and Javac are v11.0.2

Comment: Code such as `enemies.put("Peon", pn);` must be in a method, constructor or initialization block. It can't just be in the class body.

Comment: Can you use a normal IDE which would instantly indicate what the problem is?

Comment: @greg-449 ty there was a few other issues but that definitely helped!

Comment: @yegodm tried running it inside an ide as per your suggestion, same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diamonds are there to tell the compilers about the generic classes. However, the syntax should be:

```
 public Map<String,Point> enemies = new HashMap<>();
```

and default `the enemies.put("Peon", pn);` commands must take place inside the **constructor**.

Answer (score 0):

Statements in Java must be in a method.  It looks like you are trying to initialise the fields with statements like `enemies.put("Goblin", gn);`, so I suggest you create an initialisation method for each field.  Your code would become something like:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class mob{

    public Map enemies = initialiseEnemies();
    public Point pn = new Point(1, 1);
    public Point gn = new Point(5, 2);
    public Point tl = new Point(25, 8);
    public Point oc = new Point(13, 5);
    public String name;
    public int hp;
    public int dmg;

    public static Map initialiseEnemies() {
        // Build the Hashmap here and return it.
    }

    public mob(String type){
      name=type;
      hp=enemies.get(type).getX();
      dmg=enemies.get(type).getY();
    }

    public mob(){
      name="Peon";
      hp=enemies.get("Peon").getX();
      dmg=enemies.get("Peon").getY();

    }

    void setName(String name){
            this.name=name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in());
      System.out.System.out.println("Enter mob type:");
      String type = scan.nextln();
      if(mob.containsKey(type)){
        mob mob1 = new mob(type);
      }
      else{
        mob mob1 = new mob();
        mob1.setName(type);
      }

      System.out.println("You just spawned a "+mob1.name+", it has "+mob1.hp+" hp and "+mob1.dmg+" dmg!");
    }
}
```